# How to create a variable Week and setup to start on Monday in R?

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset with day records (ten years of data) and I want to create a column with a specific week of the year. The week should be start on Monday and finish on Sunday. How can I do this in R?

Here is an example dataframe:

https://github.com/daniandreza/geral/blob/main/INMET3.csv

I can identify the week with the code below, however I can´t setup the day of start (Monday) and end (Sunday)

`a=clim %>% arrange(Data.Medicao) %>% mutate(week = week(Data.Medicao), week = week - first(week) + 1)`

Comment: Hardly a minimal example. Furthermore there is a confusing mix of delimiters. Maybe your problem is really data input? I think you should offer code that inputs lat dataframe in a manner that is satisfactory to you. Voting to close as needing clarification. Suggest you paste instead the output of `dput(head(clim, 200))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that outputs the end of the week (Sunday):

```
clim %>%   
  mutate(week = Data.Medicao-as.numeric(lubridate::wday(Data.Medicao-1)) + 7)
```

For example:

```
data.frame(Data.Medicao = as.Date("2022-10-26") + 0:10) %>%
  mutate(dow = format(Data.Medicao, "%a %Y-%m-%d")) %>%
  mutate(week = Data.Medicao-as.numeric(lubridate::wday(Data.Medicao-1)) + 7)


   Data.Medicao            dow       week
1    2022-10-26 Wed 2022-10-26 2022-10-30
2    2022-10-27 Thu 2022-10-27 2022-10-30
3    2022-10-28 Fri 2022-10-28 2022-10-30
4    2022-10-29 Sat 2022-10-29 2022-10-30
5    2022-10-30 Sun 2022-10-30 2022-10-30
6    2022-10-31 Mon 2022-10-31 2022-11-06
7    2022-11-01 Tue 2022-11-01 2022-11-06
8    2022-11-02 Wed 2022-11-02 2022-11-06
9    2022-11-03 Thu 2022-11-03 2022-11-06
10   2022-11-04 Fri 2022-11-04 2022-11-06
11   2022-11-05 Sat 2022-11-05 2022-11-06
```